# Error message on Stellar Homepage

Tags: error, upgrade

[image]

The above error is there on the Stellar Launch page now, for more than a month. Further this issue persists for more than 3 months, although message claims team is 'actively' working to reoslve. How do we upgrade account without this working?

Please help resolve this immediately. There are multiple users posting about this, and suffering with inability to use accounts due to this.

Request to not move this thread (post) elsewhere and treat activation urgently.

Hoping Stellar teams corrects this really soon now, as people are desperate to upgrade old accounts and be associated wit the network and currency.